# How to convert linq query to dynamic query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, dynamic-programming

I want to create linq query which should be dynamic enough to get all properties of specific class and build expression tree for 'where' and 'select' in linq.

There is a domain model which consists of bool properties and numeric properties. Numeric properties will be used for ranges.

Example:

Domain Model

```
 public class MakeMeReal
    {
        public bool isA { get; set; }
        public bool isB { get; set; }

        public int Type1 { get; set; }
        public double Type2 { get; set; }

        public double Type3 { get; set; }
        public string Type4 { get; set; }

    }
```

Input Model:

```
  public class LinqDynamic
    {
        public bool isA { get; set; }
        public bool isB { get; set; }

        public int lowerRangeForTyp1 { get; set; }
        public int UpperRangeForTyp1 { get; set; }

        public double LowerRangeForType2 { get; set; }
        public double UpperRangeForType2 { get; set; }
    }
```

Simple query:

```
public void query(LinqDynamic dynamicInput)
        {
            SampleDbContext db = new SampleDbContext();

            var result = from m in db.MakeMeReal
                         where m.isB == dynamicInput.isB && m.isA == dynamicInput.isA &&
                               m.Type1 >= dynamicInput.lowerRangeForTyp1 && m.Type1 < dynamicInput.UpperRangeForTyp1 &&
                                m.Type2 >= dynamicInput.LowerRangeForType2 && m.Type1 < dynamicInput.UpperRangeForType2

                         select new { a = m.Type1, b = m.Type2, c = m.Type3, d = m.Type4 }; 

        }
```

I want to build query which will go through domain model and it'll build expression tree and it'll run against the inputs which'll be provided to at runtime using 'LinqDynamic' class as input parameter.

I have more than 10 booleans and 30 range selectors, and number of booleans and range selctors keeps changing as per project requirements, so it's headache to change query each time. I'd like to make it dynamic, so that it'll be agnostic to any change

I read about https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx  and some other links which I can't post here due to lack of reputation points

yet I am not sure how to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

What might help is to use a predicate in your query. There is a NuGet package that will assist you to do. The documentation will explain how to do this. See [LINQKit here](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit)